# How to scroll once in $(window).scroll() have another scroll command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a vertical photo viewer

and i need a scroll effect is once a page height when mouse wheel down.

so i have following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var H = $(window).height();
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: H + st }, 500, function () {
                console.log("finish scroll");
            });
        });
    });
```

But when i scroll once, it will repeat again and again until to the bottom.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using a counter, increment it in the scroll event, but only do your custom scroll stuff if counter === 1. In the animation callback you would then reset it.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the animation make a scroll event too. so you have a scrolling loop.
To resolve that, you can add a flag.

It's not the best way to solve your problem but you can do this => http://jsbin.com/qagayopu/2/edit

Comment: result is the same like before @@"

Comment: It almost perfect, but i don't know why "finish scroll" will toggle twice in one scroll?
This is my test page => http://crelation.com/freeMag/Viewer
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I used a counter and a timer so that the counter waits half a second after the scroll has finished..

http://jsfiddle.net/beardedSi/p45rH/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var H = $(window).height(),
    go = true;
console.log(H);
//just for visual, set the height of boxes to be same as window height 
//to check it is all working
$('.box').css('height', H + "px");

function scroller() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: '+=' + H
    }, 400, function () {
        console.log("finished");
        setTimeout(function () {
            go = true;
        }, 400);
    });
}

$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (go) {
        go = false;
        scroller();
    }
});
```

});